# Delete all files that do not have target string?

Tags: grep

[Recovered files are stored in /myPhotorec.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032173/16-04-nautlius-shift-del-file-recovery?noredirect=1#comment1678608_1032173)

The goal is to recursively grep through each file and if it does **NOT** have the string "44c9ea3abbd24" in the ***file contents*** (not the filename), then delete it.   The target was a python .py file and is randomly renamed by the file recovery name.

If this can not be done, then maybe the file containing can be copied to a directory /filtered?

Comment: string `44c9ea3abbd24` or word `44c9ea3abbd24`?

Comment: Text files that need to be retained / sorted having the string 44c9ea3abbd24

Comment: Is the string in the _content_ of the file, or in the _filename_?

Comment: @Kusalananda  Thanks for the ver good question.  **content** of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /myPhotorec -type f ! -exec grep -qF '44c9ea3abbd24' {} ';' -print -delete
```

This would find all regular files in or under the `/myPhotorec` directory, test whether they contain the given string (in the content of the file), and for each file that does not contain the string, display the pathnames and delete them.

If your `find` does not support `-delete`, then replace that part with `-exec rm {} +`.

If you want to manually confirm each deletion, change `-delete` to `-ok rm {} ';'`.

Regarding `find ... -exec ...`: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: @Kusalanananda It would be pedagogically helpful if two additional code snippets were added to the explanation: 1) the find the filenames sans target string and pipe into 2) delete command.   Preliminary test results of your solution look good on OS X.

Comment: @gatorback Piping the results of `find` into anything is not generally a good idea. One could obviously use the non-standard `-print0` with `find` and then pipe that into `xargs -0 rm` (where `-0` is likewise non-standard), but this has absolutely no benefit over using e.g. `-exec rm {} +` as in my answer.

Comment: My mistake,  you did not use pipe in your solution.  I am trying to dissect the solution because my understanding of the find and exec commands is very basic.  Breaking it down according to your thought process would accelerate the learning process

Comment: @gatorback I've added a reference to a quite long answer I've written previously on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose just do :

```
rm -rf `find /myPhotorec -name "*" | grep  -v "44c9ea3abbd24"`
```

Comment: This would perform the `grep` on filenames, not the contents of the files.

Comment: It would also not delete anything in any folder whose name contained 44c9ea3abbd24, and it would have issues with filenames containing embedded newlines. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice